# Finding if a given number in an array is even or odd c#

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone shed any light on the subject as to why this is not working, when i am testing it i'm getting lots of random even and odd outputs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] array = new int[8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 9 };
            int UserInput = 0; 

            start:

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a slot: ");
            UserInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 

            if(array[UserInput]%2 == 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Number is even");

            }else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number is odd");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

            goto start; 

        }
    }
}
```

i want to output if the cell in the array is even or odd not the inputted number so if the number five is inputted it should output even as cell five contains the number eight.

Comment: array index numeration starts with 0, so slot "5" is really number 5, not 8.

Comment: Well, actually, cell four -- not five -- contains the number 8. Array indexes are zero-based, so array[0]=1, array[1]=2, and so on. Is the user putting in a one-based number? If so, do you need to subtract one from the user input to get the index you want?

Comment: Have you tried putting array[UserInput] into a variable then either debugging it or writing it out to the console to make sure it's retrieving the value from the array properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are 0-based in C#, so you will need to deduct 1 from the user input.  Additionally, you'll want to add some check logic to make sure they're not entering a value higher than 8 or less than 1...

```
            if (UserInput < 1 || UserInput > 8) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number between 1 and 8");
                goto start;
            }
            else if(array[UserInput - 1] % 2 == 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Number is even");

            }else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number is odd");
            }
```

Comment: oh my i'm such an idiot i forgot about that, im learning you see. thanks for clearing that up

Comment: Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes :)

Comment: i like the idea of making it idiot proof with that extra if statment for values entered outside of the array size, i was going to add an extra output saying enter value between one and eight but it's always good to get in the habbit of making code unbreakable, again thank you